# Filter JBoss Access Logs By URL

Tags: jboss

I am using JBoss 6.4 EAP access logs to debug when an item hits the server.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="my.host.name"/>
            <access-log pattern="%t %a %A %b %h %m %p %q %U %r">
                <directory path="."/>
            </access-log>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

However, a monitoring tool constantly hits the server every couple of seconds to check it is up and so the access log is hard to read.

I can't turn off or change the monitoring and the code in the webserver is not mine so I can't change that either.

Is it possible to filter the access log so that it only logs when a specific url is hit?

Comment: Joining the party late... did you manage to work this out?  I have the same issue and have been scouring the internet for a solution.

Comment: No solution sorry :(

Comment: No worries!  Thanks for getting back to me :)